# Passing object of a template class to constructor of another class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a template class,

```
template< typename T >
class A
{
private:
    T *array;
public:
    A(int size)
    {
         //Initialises array with size 
    }
}
```

Now I need to have a class B which receives object of class A as constructor argument and assigns it to B local member of A reference. How do I do that? I have tried like,

```
class B
{
private:
  template<class T>
  A<T> *a;
public:
  template<class T>
  B(A<T>(int) ar){
     //assign ar to a
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**
Actually what I want to achieve here is, think that class A is a generic circular buffer, which can be initialised in one shot like `A< int > int_buffer(20);` and the same int_buffer to be used across different classes say B and C(Producer and Consumer). Is this the correct way to achieve my goal or any better approach you can suggest.

Comment: You cannot have a template member variable. To accomplish what you want, you'd need a form of [type erasure](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Erasure).

Comment: The `(int)` in `B(A<T>(int) ar)` is also suspect.

Comment: Correct. Templates are not objects.

Comment: Oh is that? @StoryTeller thanks for the response. Do you have an example of solution for similar problem?

Comment: Why not make `B` a template?

Comment: @NicoSchertler how would that help?

Comment: Making `B<T>` a template allows you to specify the type of `A<T>*` member it will use. For example, in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40240120/2642059) you could do: `A<int> a; B<int> b(&a);` But the power of templates really begins to shine in that you can also do: `A<double> a; B<double> b(&a);`

Comment: @JonathanMee updated the question, you may have better view of problem now.

Comment: @NikhilAugustine OK... do you understand my answer? That's what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll just need to make `B` a template as well:

```
template <typename T>
class B {
    A<T>* a;
public:
    B(A<T>* ar) : a(ar) {}
};
```

This runs upon the problem of shared pointers. It's unclear to me as the reader if `B<T>` will depend upon an `A<T>*` that is externally owned, or if the ownership of `A<T>*` is also being transfered to `B<T>`. C++11 has provided you some great tools for sharing pointers, and I'd strongly recommend that you take advantage of them.

If you want to share `A<T>*` but it will be owned externally use a [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).
If you transferring ownership of `A<T>*` on construction, signify that by using a [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

**EDIT:**

`B<T>` contains a member object `A<T>`. But it is held by pointer. **Holding a member by pointer or reference indicates that the objects use is shared or ownership is external.**

Without knowing your design it's hard to present a good design principle, so I'll give some optional situations here with the recommendation that you adhere to the one that matches your situation:

1. If `B<T>`'s `A<T>` member is only used within the single `B<T>` object, that member needs to be created within `B<T>`'s constructor or emplace constructed
2. If `B<T>`'s `A<T>` member is shared among *all* `B<T>` it should be a static member of the `B` class
3. If `A<T>` will be owned by `B<T>` but may only be received by pointer use a `unique_ptr<A<T>>` rather than `A<T>*` as the member type
4. If `A<T>` will be shared externally and will not be deleted as long as at least one reference to it is maintained use use `shared_ptr<A<T>>` rather than `A<T>*` as the member type
5. If `A<T>` is owned externally and may or may not have been destroyed use `weak_ptr<A<T>>` rather than `A<T>*` as the member type

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on problem of shared_ptr you have mentioned in the answer? You may refer the update i have made in the question to understand my requirement.

Comment: @NikhilAugustine I've tried to provide some heuristics on C++ smart pointer usage. The best advice is to eliminate pointer usage and minimize smart pointer usage. Anyway we're pretty far beyond the intent of the original question, so if you're still confused I'd start by scanning the smart pointer documentation that I linked. From there if you have further questions about usage, open up a new question and paste a link in a comment here and I'll come try to answer it.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Mee

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Do you want to accomplish this?

```
class B
{
private:
  A<int> *a;
public:
  B(A<int> ar){
     //assign ar to a
  }
};
```

Comment: No, type may not be int always, int in A is an argument to the constructor, which is actually size the 'array' to created.

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by `B(A<T>(int) ar)`? This is confusing us.

Comment: want to receive an object of A in B constructor, that's what I mean here.

Comment: Waht's the purpose of `(int)`?