# How to define a constructor of a template class C with template argument float with template parameters that can be cast to float?

Tags: c++, templates

I have searched for results, but the following questions are not what I want.

> - [Passing object of a template class to constructor of another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239871/passing-object-of-a-template-class-to-constructor-of-another-class)

In my case, I want to define my own template matrix class

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>&);
    template<typename U> Matrix(const Matrix<U>&);
};
```

I know it would be better to add constraints for T and U, but I omitted it for simplicity. When I only define the first two constructors as following, everything goes well.

```cpp
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix()
{

}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>&)
{

}
```

How every, if I try to add a definition of the last template constructor as follows:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<U>&)
{
}
```

The g++ complier says

```
.\test.cpp:27:1: error: no declaration matches 'Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<U>&)'
   27 | Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<U>&)
      | ^~~~~~~~~
.\test.cpp:11:26: note: candidates are: 'template<class T> template<class U> Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<U>&)'
   11 |     template<typename U> Matrix(const Matrix<U>&);
      |                          ^~~~~~
.\test.cpp:21:1: note:                 'Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>&)'
   21 | Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>&)
      | ^~~~~~~~~
.\test.cpp:15:1: note:                 'Matrix<T>::Matrix()'
   15 | Matrix<T>::Matrix()
      | ^~~~~~~~~
.\test.cpp:6:7: note: 'class Matrix<T>' defined here
    6 | class Matrix
      |       ^~~~~~
```

It seems like C++ trates `template<typename T, typename U>` and `template<class T> template<class U>` as different things. However, even if I've guessed this, I don't know exactly how to fix my code.

I don't know whether I could achieve my functionality with C++ (I guess yes). Could you please show me the most practical implementation of the functionality I want?

Comment: I know that `template<typename T> template<typename U> Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<U>&)` in definition would pass the compile, but I don't know whether it is the right approach. Add it is even more confusing for code like `template<typename T> template<typename U> requires std::is_convertible_v<U, T>`

Answer (score 2):

You are using a wrong syntax.

You may use a thing like the following

```cpp
template <typename T> struct Matrix {
    Matrix();
    template <typename U>
    Matrix(const Matrix<U>&) requires(std::is_convertible_v<U, T>);
};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<U>& rhs) requires(std::is_convertible_v<U, T>) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, U>) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much~ I didn't realize that my code would cause problem if U == T.

Comment: `template <typename U> Matrix(const Matrix<U>&)` isn't the copy constructor; having `Matrix(const Matrix<T>&);` is fine.